# Why doesn't $1/x=0$ have any solution?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question, roots, philosophy

Just out for curiosity ! Why  $1/x=0$ doesn't have any solution?

Or is it that the solution takes you to $1=0$ situation which would nullify mathematical principle that we stood for years

Educate me...And thanks

Comment: Solutions of an equation are sought in some collection of entities for which the operations are defined. What collection are we considering? Real numbers? The real numbers for which the operations involved (division in this case) are numbers $\neq0$. We can multiply the equation by any number $\neq0$ and get another equation that is true. But, $1=0x=0$ is not true. On the other hand if we search for solutions in other collections it does have a solution.

Comment: For example, if we search for solutions in the extended reals (extended with an object $i$ that satisfies $1/i=0$) then it has a solution. The reason why we can't reproduce the above to get a contradiction is that on this extension of the reals we cannot cancel $i$ from both sides of an equation. $ix=iy$ doesn't imply $x=y$.

Comment: 1 equals zero..hw's tht possible??

Comment: It's *not* possible (insert boilerplate about unital rings here), which is the point.

Comment: @The Chaz: It is. See my answer. If you disagree, I invite you to contact the author of the book I cited.

Comment: @Shaun, $1=0$ in the extended complex plane? Fascinating! Maybe you should concern yourself more with helping the OP, and less with promoting this one bit of knowledge that you picked up.

Comment: @The Chaz: It's a simple instantiation of an axiom in its definition, viz., $\frac{a}{\infty }=0$ for all $a\in\mathbb{C}$. It's important for Möbius transformations.

Comment: @Shaun Many people here are already professional mathematicians, and most likely understand/know what you are talking about. What they do is to try to answer the question in the level that the OP will feel comfortable. I suggest you take these pedagogical issues into account and try not to write stuff in the lines of "You suck, see my post," under every answer that others have given.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Asking why $\frac{1}{x} = 0$ has no solution *in the real numbers* is the same as asking if there is a real number $x$ that solves $1 = 0\cdot x$. Clearly if we multiply any real number by $0$, we will get $0$ back and so there cannot possibly be a solution. We are not limited to considering real numbers, but the argument doesn't change much when you consider other structures known as *fields*, of which the real numbers are a great example.

If you were to leave the realm of a field (e.g. stop restricting yourself to *only* the real numbers), then things get more interesting and more complicated (algebraically). If you were to include some symbols $\pm\infty$ (plus and minus infinity) with the real numbers and define them by $\frac{1}{\pm\infty} = 0$, things get a little weird. Notice that even though we say $\frac{1}{\pm\infty} = 0$, we do not want to say that $1 = 0\cdot\pm\infty$. The reason we don't is that multiplication would no longer be associative.

When multiplying real numbers, it doesn't matter how we multiply them: $a(bc) = (ab)c\,$. This is called the *associativity of multiplication*. If we introduce plus and minus infinity like we just did, this breaks down if we try to multiply by infinity haphazardly. Let's take our equation $\frac{1}{\pm\infty} = 0$ and multiply both sides by $\pm\infty$ and pretend things work out like they used to with strictly real numbers (meaning that we assume our multiplication is associative), we would have:

$$ 1 = 0\cdot\pm\infty.$$

Now, let's just see what happens when we multiply both sides by $2$. We would get

$$ 2 = 2(0\cdot\pm\infty).$$

If we try to rearrange our multiplications, we get

$$ 2 = (2\cdot0)\cdot\pm\infty = 0\cdot\pm\infty.$$

But this tells us that $1=2$ and this is very bad. Even though we said that $\frac{1}{\pm\infty} = 0$, we *do not* want to say that $1 = 0\cdot\pm\infty$. For not too dissimilar reasons, we also do not want to attempt to attribute any meaning to $\infty + (-\infty)$ or $-\infty + \infty$. Returning to the issue of multiplying infinity by $0$, we could just *define* it to be given by $0 = 0\cdot\pm\infty$ (and one does this in some contexts; see: measure theory). This definition is perfectly fine and does nice things for you, but note that we no longer obey the relationship $\frac{1}{x} = y \implies xy = 1$ (since $\frac{1}{\pm\infty} = 0$ but $0\cdot\pm\infty = 0$).

Even though we can *kind of* successfully introduce infinity as a "solution" to $\frac{1}{x} = 0$, it does give rise to some very quirky things. For these reasons we try to avoid it as much as possible, or when we can't, we try to limit ourselves to situations where the algebra we do with infinity is entirely consistent and gives meaningful results.

Answer (score 8):

Simply because if you multiply left and right member for $x$ you get: $x\times0=1$. Now, every number multiplied by $0$ is $0$.

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on the domain of $\frac{1}{x}$; that is, where $x$ can come from. The solution to $\frac{1}{x}=0$ is usually left undefined, but this is not always the case. It has a solution in the extended complex plane $\bar{\mathbb{C}}=\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty \}$: $\frac{1}{\infty }=0$.

The reason why this makes sense in $\bar{\mathbb{C}}$ is that the rules for using $\infty$ are restricted in such a way that contradictions are avoided. Things like $\infty -\infty$ are omitted.

This fact is important for things called Möbius transformations, which underpin many mathematical concepts.

Comment: See Priestley's *Introduction to Complex Analysis: Second Edition,* p19.

Comment: Is this the same as the Riemann sphere?

Comment: No: the Riemann sphere and the extended complex plane are two different things (Ibid., p18.).

Comment: Could you elaborate? I understand why this is the case, but it just seems, well, invalid. Consider the following:

$(\frac{1}{0} = \infty) \implies (\frac{1}{\infty} = 0)$, ok, all good, but since

$\frac{1}{x} \implies x = \frac{1}{x} x^2$, it follows that $\infty = \frac{1}{\infty} \infty^2$ ?

Comment: That would be off topic. It's valid. The extended complex plane is defined with a few caveats to make it rigorous.

Comment: For example, $\frac{\infty }{\infty }$ is left undefined.

Comment: The equation $1/x=0$ is meaningful even if we are assuming that $x$ is a (nonzero) real number, in which case it has no solution.  The equation may be false for all values of $x$ in the domain, but that does not make it meaningless.

Comment: Given the algebra-precalculus tag, isn't this answer somewhat overkill for the OP?

Comment: That's a fair point, Trever. And maybe, MOB, but I'm not comfortable with letting something known to be false taught as true to someone with a genuine interest. That discussion is for meta.

Comment: In the parlance I'm used to, the phrase "Riemann sphere" *is* used to describe the space $\overline{\mathbb{C}}$ you describe.

Comment: The Riemann sphere is that which is projected down to the extended complex plane, so it's as near as it makes little difference. I could be wrong.

Comment: The "Riemann sphere" and "extended complex plane" refer to different objects, but since those objects are homeomorphic (topologically isomorphic), we can say "the Riemann sphere _is_ the extended complex plane" for some sensible meaning of the word _is_.

Comment: The Riemann sphere: $\Sigma :=\{(x, y, u)\in\mathbb{R}^{3}| x^{2}+y^{2}+(u-\frac{1}{2})^{2}=\frac{1}{4}\}$. (Ibid., p17.).

Comment: @Shaun You can find a bicontinuous mapping from the Riemann sphere to the extended complex plane so Silverfish is entirely correct.

Comment: I know - I didn't say he was wrong. It was bad timing :)

Comment: @Mas: I thought something similar. But I checked the edits and noticed that someone other than the OP added that tag in an edit.

Answer (score 2):

*In the setting of a field* it is because $\frac{1}{x}=x^{-1}$ has an inverse (namely $x$ itself) - while $0$ has none.

Comment: This doesn't answer why. It's simply restating the fact.

Comment: @nik Is that so? If 0 were equal to $\frac{1}{x}$ for some $x$, it would have an inverse...

Comment: Then prove that 0 doesn't have an inverse. Yes, it's trivial, but as it is your proof is not complete and is merely restating the fact.

Answer (score 2):

It does, it the zero ring $\{0\}$. In fact, this is the only ring for which $1/x$ has a solution (multiply both sides by $x$). It also has a solution in various other systems like the extended real line as mentioned somewhere here, but those are not rings, of course.